# Hackerrank Caesar Cipher Python solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I found this example code: https://shareablecode.com/snippets/python-solution-for-hackerrank-problem-caesar-cipher-6a6b-Tike

In the for loop below:

```
for c in s:
        if c.isupper():
            res.append(symbols_up[(symbols_up.index(c)+k)%len(symbols_up)])
        elif c.islower():
            res.append(symbols_low[(symbols_low.index(c)+k)%len(symbols_low)])
        else:
            res.append(c)
```

I don't understand why we have to add `%len(symbols_up)]`? Feels like it works fine if we use `res.append(symbols_up[symbols_up.index(c)+k])`
Can someone help me understand this, please?

Comment: What would happen to e.g. `Z`?

Comment: It is to implement this part of the problem description: *"If the shift takes you past the end of the alphabet, just rotate back to the front of the alphabet."*.

Answer (score 2):

len(symbols_up) = len(symbols_low) = 26
if we don't add %26, then the integer value of the character resulting from adding k to the original integer value of the character, may exceed the integer value of the last character which is 'z' in case of lowercase and 'Z' in case of uppercase. Therefore, we add %26 (which equals len(symbols_low) and len(symbols_up)) to apply the rotation without exceeding the allowed integer value.
You can try the code below. It is much simpler and clearer than the code you attached.

```
def caesarCipher(s, k):
    res=""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i].isalpha():
            if s[i].isupper():
              res+=chr(ord('A')+(ord(s[i])-ord('A')+k)%26)
            else:
              res+=chr(ord('a')+(ord(s[i])-ord('a')+k)%26)    
        else:
            res+=s[i]
    return res
```